# Why when I add a new network interface and try to use another interface it times out?

Tags: networking, network-manager, ip, interface

I have two interfaces at the moment wifi and wired
[image]

when I plug the wired one I can no longer use wifi (wlp4s0)  if I try to do `curl --interface wlp4s0 (or 192.168.1.2) ifconfig.me` for instance It just hangs but
`curl --interface 192.168.8.100 ifconfig.me` works fine

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot you enclosed already contains the answer :)

```
default via 192.168.8.1 dev enx001e101f0000 proto dhcp metric 100
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp4s0 proto dhcp metric 600
```

Your system has two default gateways defined. In that case, your system will use mainly the gateway that has lower metric (in that case 192.168.8.1 which has metric 100) and switch to the second one only when the first one is unreachable. That's just how networking works.

So even if you force the packets to go out via 192.168.1.2, they will be sent to destination 192.168.8.1, which is not accessible from this interface, and the packets will get lost.

Comment: what can i do to solve this then ?

Comment: If you want to be able to reach **any** address from both interfaces, nothing. It just isn't designed to work that way. However, you can dedicate the second interface to some specific IP ranges by adding a route in the route table to these IP ranges via the second gateway (and remove it as a default).

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the issue. Some above suggested that you simply cannot use multiple devices in the same time which is plainly wrong.
There are 4 steps to be able to this.

- delete the default entry of the new interface from the default routing table `ip route delete default default dev <xxx>`
- add a new line with chosen name to `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables` file such as `200 example`
- route requests from that local interface to the created table `ip rule add from <user ip address in that interface> example (we just created this name above nothing magic)`
  -add a default route to that table so kernel knows where to send things `ip route add default via <router addr such as 192.168.1.1 or whatever> dev <device such as wlp4s0> table <table name we created example in this case>`
- flush the cache `ip route flush cache`

and that's it after these 4 steps you can use `curl google.com --interface wlp4s0`

You can find the source where I learned these [here](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.rpdb.simple.html). I suggest you read from beginning not just this section. the doc uses very pleasant language and lots of examples